# Methods of checking bootloader status

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

Just curious if there's any methods to check bootloader state besides using fastboot. I ask because on my device, even after unlocking successfully, the bootloader still shows that its locked when using the fastboot OEM device-info command. I know it was actually unlocked because I installed a custom ROM. I relocked after install but since it seemed to be inaccurate before I want to make sure it's locked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is...

Step 1 : Open your device’s dialer (App where you enter telephone numbers to call someone).

Step 2 : Dial the below code, it will automatically open a new windows. (if it doesn’t open a service information window on your device, you can often only access the status via fastboot)

```
*#*#7378423#*#*
```

Step 3 : Now in that window go to Service Info >> Configuration, and see if there is :

Bootloader unlock allowed - Yes
Bootloader Unlocked - Yes

Summarized from : [How to Check if your Bootloader is Locked or Unlocked](https://thebroodle.com/android/how-to-check-your-bootloader-is-locked-or-unlocked/)

Comment: I'm on Cyanogen 13. Using that code at the dialer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There are also some apps in the Play Store, like Hidden Menus, that may allow you access to the System Information menu... If not, it may not be included in CM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nothing seemed to work so I took and a chance and tried to flash recovery in fast boot and I got the device is locked message so theres my answer.

Comment: Can you link the activity of what window because I see no window getting opened in my stock Android 6.0 either?

Comment: Actually I can't... I can find references to it online (Google search Android Service Menu and go to web or images, there are several examples) but I am unable to access it on any device I available to me at the moment, a Moto G 2015 (Marshmallow), Huawei Ascend Mate 2 (Lollipop), and an old HTC Aria (Eclair) and it doesn't work in any of them, all of which are stock(ish) devices. The code should invoke the hidden application ServiceMenu.apk which may be at least partially specific to Sony devices.